# After Mac OS Update,CSS not working in Magento2

Tags: magento2, css

My CSS was working fine.But when I updated my Mac OS, CSS doesn't get applied.I have ,

1.Cleared Cache.

2.Deleted var/view-processed/pub folder and pub/static/frontend/ all folders.Deployed again.

Help me out.Thank you in advance.

Comment: you need css compiler like grunt. it will compile it.

Comment: I can compile in terminal itself.The problem is ,CSS does not get applied.

Comment: what error do you get in browser console? have you checked file permission?

Comment: Yes.I checked all file permission

Comment: What error in browser console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have updated the MAC OS and you have CSS not working, then

1.you have to go to /etc/apache2.

2.Check if httpd.conf is present or not.

3.There will be two files.

4.Copy the contents of httpd.conf~previous file and paste in httpd.conf.

Then it would work. Boom...Magic.

Comment: I applied your method.It works.@VishaliMariappan

Comment: Sounds Good.....Cheers:)